# Docker volume keeps exiting after starting

Tags: docker, docker-volume

I'm following a Docker tutorial on [Katacoda](https://www.katacoda.com/courses/docker/persisting-data-using-volumes). But I am using my personal machine and not their interactive environment. All of the following commands work as expected in the Katacoda environment but not so much on my personal machine.

The aim of the tutorial is to learn how to persist data using volumes.

My directory looks like that following

```
docker-volumes
|_ data
```

The file `data`, is a file containing the text `SET Key0 Value0`

So I follow the instructions in the tutorial and I enter the following command:

`docker run  -v /docker/redis-data:/data --name r1 -d redis redis-server --appendonly yes`

The output of the command is a hash.

When I enter `docker ps` the output shows that there is no container running. I thought the flag `-d` runs the container in the background?

If I enter `docker ps -a` I get this output:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                     PORTS               NAMES
4e1ca74b9bd7        redis               "docker-entrypoint..."   4 minutes ago       Exited (1) 4 minutes ago                       r1
```

Comment: It `Exited (1) 4 minutes ago`.  You can `docker logs r1` or use the hash that got printed out to see what it said, or `docker run` without `-d` to see the error messages in the foreground.

Comment: try -dt or -di or -dit